# struts 2 internationalization not working

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I am developing struts 2 and spring web application which suppoerts two languages: english and hindi.
I have configured internationalization but it is not working i.e. when I change the encoding from browser, the text does not change.
I have tried to even change the locale programitically but it still does not work

RegisterAction.java

```
    public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

 public String execute(){
  return "SUCCESS";
 }

 public Locale getLocale(){
  return new Locale("hi");
 }
    }
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="register" class="com.medics.action.RegisterAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/Register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Register.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"  %>
<h4><s:text name="Registration"/></h4>
```

global-messages.properties

```
hello=hello
Registration=Registration
```

global-messages_hi.properties

```
Registration=\\u2354\\u2379\\u327\\u2367\\u2344\\u2381
```

here is the snapshot of the project

struts.xml and the two messages files are in the root of the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you named your keys the same as your values in English, so you can't really tell if the English bundle is being loaded properly either. My first guess is that Struts does not know that global-messages*.properties are language bundles.

Try adding this to your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global-messages"/>
```

**Edit**

If you are sure that the English bundle is loading, then you'll want to debug the application to confirm that the Hindi locale is being set properly by Struts2. A breakpoint in your action should allow you to easily check the value of `getLocale()`.

Comment: i have already defined the global-messages resoulse bundle in struts.properties file English bundle is loading properly since when i change the value in that bundle, it is reflected on the web page